# función mail() en PHP no envía correo, sin mensajes de error. Usando XAMMP

Tags: php, apache, email, xampp

Estoy tratando de usar la función **mail()** en PHP con APACHE en **XAMMP**.
En un principio salía este error:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
>   25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
>   ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Evaluacion PHP\pages\enviar_mail.php
>   on line 33

En "**php.ini**" tenía todo bien, así que me fijé en la carpeta "sendmail", y en el archivo "**sendmail.ini**".

Modificando en "sendmail.ini" por el siguiente valor: **"smtp_server=localhost"** se solucionó (o sea, deja de aparecer el error y aparece la pantalla en blanco), pero no llega ningún correo ni tengo manera de ver donde está el error.. alguna idea?

**P.D:** Mi idea no es usar **PHPMailer**, sino la función **mail()** porque es para un práctico que pide expresamente usar ése método, por lo que supongo que el problema estaría en la configuración de Apache.

Comment: Puedes agregar la configuracion de sendmail? completa?

Comment: El error se te esta generando porque el servicio del smtp no se te esta ejecutando verifica que este iniciado en la consola del xampp

Comment: @YoelRodriguez cómo verifico el estado del smtp por consola?

Comment: Si tienes el xampp en windows en instala una consola para administrar los servicio por ahí lo puedes verificar en el caso de la 1.73 el servidor de correo que utiliza es un **mercury**

Comment: @YoelRodriguez **Mercury SMTP Server** me marca el estado como **"Ready"**, pero sigue sin enviar los correos.

Comment: @luis entra en la consola de administración del servidor tener y inicia los servicios  y verifica la configuración del servicio smtp que este correcta y para comprobar que el servicio de smtp este funcionando lo puedes hacer con un **telnet**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en Mercury (mejor dicho, en el uso de Mercury). Para usar tu servidor como servidor de correos es necesario que tengas una IP pública fija y registros MX en el servidor DNS que alberga tu dominio; es posible que el correo haya salido de tu computadora (o no) sin que te dieras cuenta y que el servidor de destino lo haya rechazado, recomiendo dos cosas aquí:

- Envía el correo a una cuenta local de Mercury SMTP para que el MTA entregue el correo de forma local.
- Usa un servidor SMTP externo como GMAIL.

Puedes usar [fake sendmail for Windows](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail), en el `.ini` de fakesendmail ingresa tus credenciales de GMAIL similar a esto:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=456
smtp_ssl=ssl
auth_username=algun_mail@gmail.com
auth_password=********
force_sender=algun_mail@gmail.com
```

Después en el `ini` de PHP quitas toda la configuración y cambias el sendmail path:

```
sendmail_path = "C:\ruta_fakesendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

No te olvides de configurar la cuenta de GMAIL para que acepte conexiones SMTP externas y si usas 2 step auth debes crear una contraseña sepecial para este servicio.

Comment: Lo pude resolver como lo dijiste Solrac, muchas gracias a vos y a Yoel por la ayuda prestada.